# How to rearrange the sortOrder of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array that contains objects inside and each object has a key called sortOrder and a number assigned to it and the object gets sorted based on the order. How can I change the sordOrder property with any number I like dynamically, without manually changing the sortOrder property? I tried with an if statement but it didn't work and I don't know why, here is my code:

```js
const array = [{
  name: "sam",
  sortOrder: 0
}, {
  name: "i",
  sortOrder: 4
}, {
  name: "that",
  sortOrder: 2
}, {
  name: "am",
  sortOrder: 3
}];

// Reordering the sortOrder values:
if (array.name === 'sam') {
  array.sortOrder = 4
}
array.sort((a, b) => a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder);

const list = document.getElementById("list");
const makeListItem = name => {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = name;
  return li;
};
array.forEach(item => list.appendChild(makeListItem(item.name)));
```

```html
<ol id="list">
</ol>
```

Here is a [link to a CodePen](https://codepen.io/stephenthecurt/pen/GVNKKv?editors=1010&fbclid=IwAR2iscQPzvb76yyHXXO-rumudB30WmdV4h99PDTbGIWrdlV7Lml1YUf8XuM).

Comment: What do you mean by *"How can I change the sordOrder property with any number I like dynamically, without manually changing the sortOrder property?"*

Comment: You are referencing a `name` property on the array in the `if` statement, but an array has no property named `name`. Same with `sortOrder`.

Comment: I want to make a check with an if statement like  if(array.name === 'sam') {
    array.sortOrder = 4
}

Comment: But `array` has no `name`. It's a list of objects, each of which has a `name` property, but not the array itself.

Comment: Once you update `sam`, there will be 2 items with `sortOrder = 4`. What happens to `name: "i"` object? Do they swap the order or are you okay with duplicate `sortOrder`?

Comment: @adiga they should swap the order

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your code

```
if(array.name === 'sam') {
  array.sortOrder = 4
}
```

is that the `array` doesn't have the property `name` or `sortOrder`, it is the objects *inside* this array which have these properties.

Instead, you can use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on your array to get the object inside your array with the `name` of "sam" and then change its sortOrder like so:

```js
const array = [{name: "sam", sortOrder: 0},{name: "i", sortOrder: 4},{name: "that", sortOrder: 2},{name: "am", sortOrder: 3}];

const samObj = array.find(obj => obj.name === "sam");
if (samObj) { // if an an object with the name of `sam` could be found, then we can safely modify its sortOrder property
  samObj.sortOrder = 4
}
array.sort((a, b) => a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder); 

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the `name` property of the *array*, not the items, which of course, does not exist. You should make a check against each element in the array, and edit the property if the check passes.

You can use `find` to get the item, and then directly edit the property:

```js
const array = [{name: "sam", sortOrder: 0},{name: "i", sortOrder: 4},{name: "that", sortOrder: 2},{name: "am", sortOrder: 3}];

const item = array.find(o => o.name === "sam")
if(item) item.sortOrder = 4

array.sort((a,b) => a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder);

console.log(array)
```

For ease, you can write it as a function:

```js
const array = [{name: "sam", sortOrder: 0},{name: "i", sortOrder: 4},{name: "that", sortOrder: 2},{name: "am", sortOrder: 3}];

const editOrder = (n, o) => (array.find(o => o.name === n) || {}).sortOrder = o

editOrder('sam', 4)

array.sort((a,b) => a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder);

console.log(array)
```

Comment: You could directly use `find` instead of using `findIndex` and then accessing the index

Comment: @adiga Does `find`'s return reference the array?

Comment: It gets the object based on the provided callback and undefined if none of the object satisfies the condition